# Limit the groups exposed in Group profile field

Tags: profile, groups

I'd like to use the Group field in a profile so people can sign up for our mailing lists. However, the Group field exposes ALL of our public groups, and I want it to to expose only the public MAILING list groups. Is there a way to do that?

Using CiviCRM 5.3.1 with WordPress 4.9.6.

Comment: Have you considered using civicrm/mailing/subscribe (drupal) or for WP i think https://civicrm.org/update-my-mailing-preferences?page=CiviCRM&reset=1 - and checked which groups show there

Comment: That doesn't seem to work but maybe I'm not doing it right. Would it be mywebsite.com/civicrm.org/mailing/subscribe? Do I need to enable anything to do that?

Comment: there may be a drupal permission

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how to make it work in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change the visibility of the groups to `User and User Admin Only` to hide the group display from all the public pages or profile.

If you don't want to do that, you might want a developer to add a js file on the profile rendering page and hide extra group values using javascript.